# External login created in SQL/ Synapse Analytics but not in server_principals

Tags: azure-synapse

On the master db of a Serverless Synapse Analytics instance an external login is created for AAD Security Group.

```
CREATE LOGIN [sg-aad-name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

The login does not show up in the table sys.server_principals.
The following query doesn't return any results:

```
SELECT SUSER_SID('sg-aad-name')
```

But I can't ALTER or DROP the login. The message that is returned: 'it does not exist or you do not have permission'. When I try to create it again, it indicates that is already exists.
When I try to add the login to a server role, it again indicates 'it does not exist or you do not have permission'.

I have SQL Administrator rights and so does the AAD security group for which I try to create the login. This issues appears on two instances. On another instance it worked and is functioning properly.

What am I overlooking? Can someone enlighten me on what is happening here or how this can be solved? I want to create an external login, have it visible in the sys.server_principals table and add to server role.

Tried all statements above. Read various blog posts and fora such a Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. The security group already had a login in sys.server_principals where the name was the Azure object ID of the security group. Dropping this login allowed for creation of the new login. This new external login was stored under the name of the security group in sys.server_principals.